# compile errors with findViewById() and TextView

Tags: android

This code is from a example that I am learning from:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        TextView hello =(TextView} findViewById(R.id.hello);
        hello.setText("on your bike!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is a learning project example that I'm following along with. The code matches exactly as the example, but, it keeps giving me a few error messages.
I'm having two problems. Firstly on the line "`TextView hello =(TextView} findViewById(R.id.hello);`" The (TextView) is getting a compile error and the error description i'm getting is "TextView cannot be resolved to a variable". I have looked up a few other examples with situations that use very similar code. Everything i have looked at says it should work. Am I really missing something here?
Secondly, in the very same line, I get another error. For the section "`findViewById`" it gives the me following compile error "Return type for the method is missing". Again I have done research on this problem and it seems to be common, yet, the answers given to the problem seem to very as well do the results that work for different individuals.  One example was to use "`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.hello)`" and "`getView().findViewById(R.id.hello)`". Neither of these methodes worked for me. If there is a part here that I'm missing, I don't know what it is. Now, I know there are a other methods to do thiis, that being said, since I have been told you can do it this way, I would like to know how to make it work as to expand my knowledge bass.

Thanks ahead of time for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this : `(TextView}`

Change to : `(TextView)` with `)`

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry. I was working so long with code before this, my eyes got a but blurry. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnStewart sometimes...this is just happen man, no matter who we are LOL. Please accept my answer (click the check mark in the left) :)

Comment: What IDE are you using btw, I think they all handle typos.